# Confusing Usage of Perfect Tenses

Tags: past-vs-past-perfect

Actually, as you may guess, I'm not a native English speaker, in fact it's third language that I've leaned. Persian and Azari Turkish are my mother tongues. By the way, I have to get an IELTS cert and I should prepare myself to do so. But I have problem with tenses. I always get confused about perfect tenses. I really can't know whether I should use simple present/past or present/past perfect. I'm looking for some sort of flowcharts to check which tense should be used. For example I think I should use simple past when there is a "certain time", e.g. "yesterday" or "on March 9th". Could you please help me understand usage of perfect tenses. Here are some sentences you may use to explain the situation:

> Concorde, the world’s fastest passenger plane, (develop) ____ by France and Britain together.
>
> In the 1950s, both countries dreamed of having a supersonic plane, and the project (start) ____ in 1962.
>
> £1.5 billion (spend) ____ on developing the Concorde, and it (test) ____ for over 5.000 hours, which makes it the most tested plane in history.
>
> The first passenger plane (introduce) ____ by British Airways and Air France in 1976.

I know these are passive voices, but that's not the thing I'm talking about. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Mehdi, I have edited my answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are **correct** that the past simple is used when there's a definite period (such as in 19__ or so) in the past. It is a key to indicate that all the actions happened at that time and thus are considered finished.

> Concorde, the world’s fastest passenger plane, (1)**was developed** by France and Britain together.
>
> In the 1950s, both countries dreamed of having a supersonic plane, and the project (2)**started** in 1962.
>
> £1.5 billion (3)**was spent** on developing the Concorde, and it (4)**was tested** for over 5.000 hours, which makes it the most tested plane in history.
>
> The first passenger plane (5)**was introduced** by British Airways and Air France in 1976.

---

1- The process of developing the plane has been **finished** and **completed** in the past; it is past simple tense.

2- The project of the completed and developed plane has **also** happened in the past. In other words, it **started** and **finished** in the past **entirely**.

3- The money has been spent in the past. It is a **finished** action.

4- Didn't they finished it alongside all its procedure steps!? The testing action is one of the steps of making and developing the plane. It **happened** and **finished** in the past **too**.

5- Whatever **was introduced** as anything, it is something that happened in the past in 1976 which is a period that has been passed.